# What does Selenium Service class do?

Tags: selenium

I'm curious what the Selenium class called "Service" is.

Would this be useful for setting up a Chrome driver as opposed to invoking a webdriver through `my_driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)`?

I looked up the docs but they're not helpful in describing the purpose:

- https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Service` is the new class introduced in selenium 4 to start a webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(your_chromedriver_path))
```

The previous method is deprecated:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=your_chromedriver_path)
```

in fact if you run it, then it raises a warning

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

Answer (score 1):

This service is introduce to manage the driver process. So that you can kill it after your tests are done.

Basically invoking `quit` does not put any obligations to webdriver to stop existing as the process. On the contrary webdriver is a service that is aimed to process concurrent sessions from different clients. So once your tests are stopped the webdriver might still be running.

When you start your tests using `Service` you now get an interface to kill that remote process using the obtained reference.

Comment: So the updated process of using `Service` is just more control of the underlying resource?

Comment: @engineer-x Exactly. Not just new way to start a browser but also to check if your driver is running and kill it because before in Selenium 3 there were no supported way to do that.

Comment: Can we replace driver=new remotewebdriver () with this service ? If yes can we use it for android emulator chrome browser as well.