# Error when I try to deploy selenium code on pythonanywhere

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, path, pythonanywhere

I try to deploy this code on pythonanywhere

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

atc

but got an error:

```
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GS-Binance/chromedriver.exe'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hincsjn/GS-Binance/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("GS-Binance/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.googl
e.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I tried lot's of paths, but I didn't make sence(

Comment: You need to add the location of your Chrome driver to your PATH environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72354624/what-does-selenium-service-class-do you should move into using Service.

Comment: See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your bash console (next to Dashboard) and issue this command:

```
echo $PATH
```

It displays your command paths separated with a period (`.`) or colon (`;`).

Save your `chromedriver.exe` in any of those paths, then you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

remove the extension from the `chromedriver.exe`. I think it will help