# WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

It's been a while since I used Selenium and webdriver.

I used this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import requests
import json

import pandas as pd
import re
import time

from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_pandas

pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

import os
os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0' # Permet de masquer les informations de scraping inutiles qui encombrent la page (a faire quand il y a pas de pb avec le code)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
```

And I have this error:

> :1: DeprecationWarning: executable_path
> has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object   driver =
> webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')

---

> WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in 
> ----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
>
> 3 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py
> in assert_process_still_running(self)
> 117         return_code = self.process.poll()
> 118         if return_code:
> --> 119             raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
> 120
> 121     def is_connectable(self) -> bool:
>
> WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly
> exited. Status code was: -6

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

I used google chrome : Version 109.0.5414.75 (Build officiel) (64 bits)
The chromedriver :  ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 but in 32 on windows

Comment: Try [selenium service class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72355025/14900791) as the error says.

Comment: Thanks but I have the same error : WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Comment: In fact it's was beacause I can't used Selenium with google colab. It's ok with Anaconda. have a nice day.